# Auto run command from vscode extension on file save

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, vscode-extensions

I can I auto execute 2 separate commands upon file saving in VS Code?

###### I want the two commands to do the following:

**1.** Format the document in focus 
    **2.** Sort the documents Imports

Comment: Perhaps a setting for auto sort import on save just like the one for format on save?

Comment: There a few `run on save` extensions available.  I have never tried them though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no default support for running Tasks, or Commands, on save (onSave). However, there is 3rd party support via the VSCode extension **"Run on Save"**.

Here is the link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave

This is a very popular extension, I used it once a while back and it worked well for my use-case.

Also if you just want to lint, or format code, on save that can be done through VSCode settings.

###### EDIT June 20, 2021 @ 9:04pm UTC

If you want to add the command to your settings you have to configure a the extension, which is explained in the extensions README.md, that can be viewed by clicking on the extensions icon in the VSCode extensions explorer.

### Configuration

Add "emeraldwalk.runonsave" configuration to user or workspace settings.

- "shell" - (optional) shell path to be used with child_process.exec options that runs commands.
- "autoClearConsole" - (optional) clear VSCode output console every time commands run. Defaults to false.
- "commands" - array of commands that will be run whenever a file is saved.

  - "match" - a regex for matching which files to run commands on

  > NOTE Since this is a Regex, and also in a JSON string backslashes have to be double escaped such as when targetting folders. e.g. "match": "some\\\\folder\\\\.*"

  - "cmd" - command to run. Can include parameters that will be replaced at runtime (see Placeholder Tokens section below).
  - "isAsync" (optional) - defaults to false. If true, next command will be run before this one finishes.

#### Sample Config

This sample configuration will run echo statements including the saved file path.
In this sample, the first command is async, so the second command will get executed immediately even if first hasn't completed.
Since the second isn't async, the third command won't execute until the second is complete.

```
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "match": ".*",
            "isAsync": true,
            "cmd": "echo 'I run for all files.'"
        },
        {
            "match": "\\.txt$",
            "cmd": "echo 'I am a .txt file ${file}.'"
        },
        {
            "match": "\\.js$",
            "cmd": "echo 'I am a .js file ${file}.'"
        },
        {
            "match": ".*",
            "cmd": "echo 'I am ${env.USERNAME}.'"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Configuring a command to execute when you save, isn't going to be as simple as hitting [F1] to open the quick-input, and finding the extensions task that you want to run. You will have to follow the instructions, and when you get stuck, you might have to come back and ask a question about the issue you are experiencing, or google it however; if your a Linux user, or you have a lot of MS-Dos or Powershell experience, this will be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Great, and how would I use this to run commands linked to vscode extensions?

Comment: @CallumOKane Im editing it into the answer, gimme 1 min

Comment: @jD3V Note that, in the case of Python, `Run on Save` doesn't know about active virtual environments in the workspace, so you'll need to manually activate them. Just a precaution.

Comment: @JΛYDΞV that's a nice extension! I would love to see directly in my terminal window, which is integrated into my VS CODE IDE, that the command is triggered. Any idea how I can make that happen? In my case, I'm using it to trigger automatically a docker build command, and I would like to see the logs of the image build.

Comment: For now, I'm solving it by writing the output to a file like this:

"settings": {
  "emeraldwalk.runonsave": {

   "commands": [
    {
     "match": "YourRegexExpHere",
     "isAsync": true,
     "cmd": "echo $(date) - 'CurrentTaskName' >> ~/Developer/auto_run_logs.txt",
    },
    {
     "match": "DockerFileName",
     "isAsync": true,
     "cmd": "docker build -t TageYourDocker -f DockerFileName.Dockerfile . >> ~/Developer/auto_run_logs.txt 2>&1",
    },
   ]
  }
 }

Comment: If somebody else encounters the same problem, I have here what I learned:

To see the print statements (`echo`) output in your VS Code IDE, choose OUTPUT in the panel where you also find your Terminal and pick in the dropdown to the right `Run On Save`.

Answer (score 6):

If You want to get just the code formatting feature, instead of installing RunOnSave, check that the native setting of IDE is activated.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

As I noted in a comment, there are a number of "run on save" extensions.  Here is one that will run external commands, like those from an extension.  And it seems to be more recent and better maintained than some.

[Run It On](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fsevenm.run-it-on)

Sample setting:

```
"runItOn": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "match": ".*",
            "isShellCommand" : false,
            "cmd": "myExtension.amazingCommand"
        },
        {
            "match": "\\.txt$",
            "cmd": "echo 'Executed in the terminal: I am a .txt file ${file}.'"
        }
    ],
    "watchers": [
        {
            "match": "**/*.js",
            "cmd": "echo 'Changes detected on js files.'"
        }
    ]
}
```

`myExtension.amazingCommand` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Works well - note that when changing the config you need to exit/restart VSCode for the new commands to work. (at least I had to).

Answer (score 3):

In order to above answer for https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave.

How to make the above extension work:

In order to see the console output, you have to be in the Output tab and select the Run On Save option in the dropdown. The extension was created before the integrated terminal existed and hasn't seen a major update in a while.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up to the provided answer:

If you are using Python, the `Run on Save` extension (and any `tasks.json` for that matter) in VSCode **do not see** (automatically recognize) any active virtual environments in your workspace.

All commands are run as if from a shell in the current working directory **before** your environment is activated. (If you think about it, thinks makes sense because it doesn't know what language/program you are going to run)

To run a python command on save from within the context of a virtual environment, first manually activate it:

```json
"cmd": ".venv\\Scripts\\activate.bat && py -m your_script.py"
```

Otherwise, the global python installation is used.

If you are using a command from a 3rd party package (e.g. `pyupgrade`) and you don't have that installed in your global python, nothing gets run. **Even worse**, if you have multiple python installations and both have the package installed, the package that gets run is the one from your global python, which may not be what you want.